# Pandas error: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
timestamp   topAsk  topBid  CPA midprice    CPB spread  s

    0   2019-03-14 00:00:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    1   2019-03-14 00:01:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    2   2019-03-14 00:02:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    3   2019-03-14 00:03:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    4   2019-03-14 00:04:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    5   2019-03-14 00:05:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    6   2019-03-14 00:06:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    7   2019-03-14 00:07:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    8   2019-03-14 00:08:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
    9   2019-03-14 00:09:00 0.00005000  0.00004957  0.00004979  0.00004979  0.00004979  4.3E-7  0.008636272343844145410725045190
```

When I try to add a new column using the following line of code: `df['gamma'] = ((df['midprice'] - df['CPB']) / df['spread'])` I have the following error message= `Pandas error: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]`

Is it because my column `df['spread']` is really small? I am a bit stuck, thanks!

df.info() shows:

[image]

Comment: What does `df.info()` show for those columns? Are they float or `decimal`?

Comment: I just added a picture of df.info() :)

Comment: Don't post an image, anyway it looks like those are python objects what does `type(df['CPB'].iloc[0])` show? and also for those other columns

Comment: They are all `decimal.Decimal`

Comment: try: `df['gamma'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['midprice'] - row['CPB']/row['spread']), axis=1)`

Comment: what does `df.dtypes` show?

Comment: Looking at numbers your df should have `float64` data type. But `info` shows `objects`. Probably you should convert them to float and then your formula will work.

Comment: @EdChum, it worked but I have an error at line 26233 : `([<class 'decimal.DivisionByZero'>], 'occurred at index 26233')` do you have a solution to put `df['gamma']` at zero for that one or get rid of this line? thanks!

Comment: You can either drop those rows or replace with `1` so it's a no op when performing the function e.g. `df['gamma'] = df[df['spread'] != 0].apply(lambda row: (row['midprice'] - row['CPB']/row['spread']), axis=1) ` or df['spread'] = df['spread'].replace(0,1)` and then run my code

Answer (score 8):

`decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionUndefined'>]` means that you have somewhere a `0/0` division using `Decimal` values. It is easy to find a workaround by first testing whether `df['spread']` is 0, but you really should try to find why and how a value that is intended to be a divisor can be null. And in that case I would use NaN as result. Code could be:

```
df['gamma'] = df.apply(lambda x:
     (x['midprice'] - x['CPB']) / x['spread'] if x['spread'] != 0
     else decimal.Decimal('NaN'), axis=1)
```